# Can not create encrypted table in MariaDb

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I'd like to create encrypted tables in MariaDb.

Following the doc for "Data-at-Rest Encryption":

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/data-at-rest-encryption-overview/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/encryption-key-management/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-encryption-overview/

I did:

```
(echo -n "1;" ; openssl rand -hex 32 ) | sudo tee -a  /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile
(echo -n "2;" ; openssl rand -hex 32 ) | sudo tee -a  /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile
(echo -n "3;" ; openssl rand -hex 32 ) | sudo tee -a  /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile
(echo -n "4;" ; openssl rand -hex 32 ) | sudo tee -a  /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile
(echo -n "5;" ; openssl rand -hex 32 ) | sudo tee -a  /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile

sudo openssl rand -hex 128 > /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key

sudo openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha1 -pass file:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key -in /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile -out /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
```

It creates the 3 files:

```
ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 21 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 21 16:16 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  335 Oct 21 17:04 keyfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  352 Oct 21 17:14 keyfile.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  257 Oct 21 17:09 keyfile.key
```

Then in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf, into the [mysqld] section, I added:

```
plugin_load_add = file_key_management

file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CBC

innodb_encrypt_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
innodb_encryption_threads = 4
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1
```

Then I restart mariadb:

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

Then I try to create an encrypted table:

```
mysql -uroot -p
CREATE DATABASE foo;
USE foo;

CREATE TABLE a (i int) ENGINE=InnoDB ENCRYPTED=YES;
```

But I get an error, and I cannot figure out why:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `foo`.`a` (errno: 140 "Wrong create options")
```

And it works when I do not specified `ENCRYPTED=YES`, or if I specify NO:

```
CREATE TABLE b (i int) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE b (i int) ENGINE=InnoDB ENCRYPTED=NO;
```

Then:

```
show tables;

+---------------+
| Tables_in_foo |
+---------------+
| a             |
| b             |
+---------------+
```

Maybe the encryption is turn on by defaut with my config. I've tried multiple combinaison ON/OFF without effect.

I've also found this query, but it only gives results for table "b" and nothing for table "a" :

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.innodb_tablespaces_encryption;

+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+----------------------+
| SPACE | NAME  | ENCRYPTION_SCHEME | KEYSERVER_REQUESTS | MIN_KEY_VERSION | CURRENT_KEY_VERSION | KEY_ROTATION_PAGE_NUMBER | KEY_ROTATION_MAX_PAGE_NUMBER | CURRENT_KEY_ID | ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING |
+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+----------------------+
|     9 | foo/b |                 0 |                  0 |               0 |                   0 |                     NULL |                         NULL |              1 |                    0 |
+-------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+----------------+----------------------+
```

And:

```
SELECT st.SPACE, st.NAME, te.ENCRYPTION_SCHEME, te.ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING
FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION te
JOIN information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLES st ON te.SPACE = st.SPACE

+-------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
| SPACE | NAME  | ENCRYPTION_SCHEME | ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING |
+-------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
|     9 | foo/b |                 0 |                    0 |
+-------+-------+-------------------+----------------------+
```

Maybe /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf is not the good file to add my config, but /etc/mysql/my.cnf is (allmost) empty. I tried multiples files without any good result. The installation was made on Debian 12 with `apt install mariadb-client mariadb-server` and `mysql_secure_installation`.

---

### EDIT

I finally found a solution, even though the documentation says it's not necessary:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN FILE_KEY_MANAGEMENT SONAME 'file_key_management';
```

Comment: specify a `ENCRYPTION_KEY_ID=4` at the same time

Comment: THANKS @danblack . Indeed, you must indicate the key.

Comment: I managed to find a solution, cf. below.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching for what's wrong, I finally found it.

Contrary to what is written in the documentation (sic. "no additional package installations are necessary"), the plugin must be installed:

```
mysql -uroot -p
INSTALL PLUGIN FILE_KEY_MANAGEMENT SONAME 'file_key_management';
```

Comment: which page is that? I'd like to correct it.

Comment: @danblack It is on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/file-key-management-encryption-plugin/ if I understand well. The shared library is in the main server package, so no additional package installations are necessary. Then Installing the Plugin : This can be specified as a command-line argument to mysqld or it can be specified in a relevant server option group in an option file. For example: plugin_load_add = file_key_management